# Aligning dynamically generated form fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a form that has some fields and then some more generated by jquery. The problem is the new ones do not align to the existing ones. I tried fiddling with CSS, but it didn't work. This is **exactly** this guy's problem, but he didn't get a response:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218225/dynamically-generated-jquery-table-row-not-aligning-correctly

This is my form:

```
<form id="recipe" name="recipe" action="create.php" method="post">
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <div id="labels">            
        <label class="label" for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <label class="label" for="unit">Unit:</label>
        <label class="label" for="ingredient">Ingredient:</label>
    </div>

    <div id="inputs">
        <div class="fields">
            <input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" />
            <input class="unit" name="unit[]" type="text" />
            <input class="ingredient" name="ingredient[]" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
      <a id="add" href="#"><span>» Add ingredient.</span></a>
   </div>              

   <div>
        <h2>Directions</h2>
        <textarea name="preparacion" rows="10" cols="51"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
    <input type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
</form>
```

And this is the JS I'm using to generate the additional fields:

```
        var count = 0;
        $(function(){
        $('a#add').click(function(){
                count += 1;
                $('#inputs').append('<div class="fields"><input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" /><input class="unit" name="unit[]" type="text" /><input class="ingredient" name="ingredient[]" type="text" /></div>');
});
});
```

However, the result is as follows:

> [image]

(please remove the spaces, it won't let me posts images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the original row of input you have the inputs separated by a new line or a space character, when you add the new row you are appending all the code together and it renders one input closer to the previous one.

Simple solution, add a space after each input in the js code:

```
var count = 0;
    $(function(){
    $('a#add').click(function(){
            count += 1;
            $('#inputs').append('<div class="fields"><input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" /> <input class="unit" name="unit[]" type="text" /> <input class="ingredient" name="ingredient[]" type="text" /></div>');
});`
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked flawlessly. I am new to JS and didn't know the spaces/new lines got rendered as well. Thanks to xelber too!

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between the inputs?

```
$('#inputs').append('<div class="fields"><input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" /> <input class="unit" name="unit[]" type="text" /> <input class="ingredient" name="ingredient[]" type="text" /></div>');
```